# Are you allowed to `startLocationUpdate` in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, uiapplicationdelegate, background-task

I've seen many answers here that say you can. Some say you can but you must wrap it inside a backgroundTask which I find redundant because it's already included in the plist. Others that say you can't do it and must go for other options.

However the Apple docs says:

Reading from [`locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1621553-locationmanagerdidpauselocationu)

> You might use your implementation of this method to start region
>   monitoring at the user's current location or enable the visits
>   location service to determine when the user starts moving again.
>   **Another alternative is to restart location services immediately with a
>   reduced accuracy (which can save power) and then return to a greater
>   accuracy only after the user starts moving again.**

I tried the restart location inside my `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates` callback:

```
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
locationManager.distanceFilter = 200
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

but it doesn't work. I get no locationUpdates anymore!

I also tried wrapping it inside a backgroundTask as follows:

```
var changeLocationTrackingType:UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?

func changeLocationTrackingInBackground()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){ [unowned self] in
        self.changeLocationTrackingType = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({ () -> Void in

            self.changeLocationTrackingType = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

        })

          locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
          locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
          locationManager.distanceFilter = 200
          locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
          locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
          self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
}
```

FWIW I'm not talking about creating a region, nor I'm talking about significantLocationTracking. I'm talking about beginning `startLocationUpdate` after your locationTracking has been stopped either by you or the system.

Most answers suggest you to use a timer to change accuracy, but I purely want to stop and be able to start again. Is there anyway to do such?

Also I know that you must be on an active runloop when you want to do `startLocationUpdate`, just not sure **how** you can guarantee that.

Comment: yea i was allowed but what kind of issue you faced . what is your requirement .

Comment: @NazmulHasan What issue I faced? After I get the `locationManagerDidPauseLocationUpdates` callback if I do `startUpdateLocation`...nothing happens I get no location updates...

Comment: can you share your full code what you did for location update . is there  any time farm or when element(user device) moving then update to location to the server . something this type of scenario

Comment: @NazmulHasan I don't understand your comment. You want me to share what I do in `didUpdateLocation`?